# Help identifying connectors

Tags: connector, identification

Can someone help me identify these connectors, I haven't seen them before, tried searching on digikey but there are a lot of connectors, and some of them don't have pictures so it's proving difficult to identify it.

I need both types female and male of the connectors.

And tools that I would need to attach them to wires.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What kind of device is in the first picture?

Comment: A broader view of the first connector would be more helpful. Also it looks like something you plug and twist, hence a side view wouldn't be unwelcome.

Comment: I quess that the first connector is some kind of mini-DIN 8 connector.

Comment: It's from a motor device, and sensor 3 wires for the motor and 2 for the sensor. It will be difficult to give a broader view as I can't remove it from the enclosure

Comment: I found a similar cable on AliExpress that has the same connectors.

Comment: Maybe you can add some details on what it turned out to be? At the moment this answer doesn't seem useful for anyone else looking for them in the future.

Comment: I have no idea how the connectors are called but from the measurements I took looks like the white ones are Molex 0.062". So for the moment it doesn't matter, if it ever breaks I will just replace the connectors with ones I can find more easily here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white ones look like Molex 0.062" Connectors to me, the other one is very hard to tell. Download a data sheet and take some measurements, there are other sizes available so check to see if they are the 0.062"s.

[Molex 0.062" Product Line](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=standard_062&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction)

Comment: The white ones are Molex 0.062"

Comment: As for the other one I can't find DIN 8 that has the same measurments

Answer (score 0):

The black round connector is definitely a TE [CPC series connector](http://www.te.com/usa-en/product-206433-1.html). Based on the picture it's a size 11-8 panel mount. You can find the compatible plug and correct contacts on the supplied link.

Comment: Looks the same. I measured the diameter to about 0.682" which is more or less the same as on the connector which is 0.688".

Comment: I was going to say the same thing. You can find them on Digikey, but OnlineComponents usually has lower prices on connectors.